# Javascript : Access to specific information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

I have a variable `Non_performance` that contains the following information and I want to access only to `remarks` so how can this be done??

`Non_performance` = {"code": 3, "codeName": "BOB", "remarks": "LION"}

Comment: `Non_performance.remarks` or `Non_performance["remarks"]`

Comment: Non_performance?.remarks

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve it by object destructuring.

```
const { remarks } = Non_performance
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to access the property of an object.

`Non_performance.remarks` if you know the name of the property,
`Non_performance['remarks']`. You can also pass a variable inside the array brackets this way incase you want to dynamically access the property.

ES6 has come out with a way to pick out each individual property using destructuring

`const { remarks } = Non_performance`